# How to map drop-downs according to JSON array length

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, react-native

This question is about react native mobile application. I want to know how to generate dropdown according to my API JSON array length values.

In my case output values are like this

```
eg:- Choice 1 (Label of the Drop Down)
           -Sub Choice 1 . (Value Data)
           -Sub Choice 2 (Value Data)
           -Sub Choice 3 (Value Data)

   Choice 2 (Label of the second Drop Down)
           -Sub Choice 1 . (Value Data)
           -Sub Choice 2 . (Value Data)
           -Sub Choice 3 . (Value Data)
```

Like this, if API response gives Choice 1, Choice 2 -> then I need to generate 2 dropdowns accordingly.

This is my code and according to my code I only get the last Choice and Choice Data of API response array

I'm using the react-native-material-dropdown library and I need to map this accordingly with JSON array length

```
 if(responseText.success == true)
    {
      var count = Object.keys(responseText.data).length;  //Getting Array Data Length
      let drop_down_data = [];  //  For Dropdown box
      for(var i=0;i<count;i++){
        // Next Loop for Fetching Choice Items
        var t_count = Object.keys(responseText.data[i].choiceItems).length;
        for(var j=0;j<t_count;j++){

          var Add_On_Name = responseText.data[i].name
          console.log(Add_On_Name)
          this.setState({addOn_name: Add_On_Name});

          this.setState({riceTypeData:responseText.data[i].choiceItems[j].name});
          drop_down_data.push({ value: responseText.data[i].choiceItems[j].name}); 

        }

      }
      this.setState({ drop_down_data , progressDialog:false}); // Set the new state

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps.

```
//This is the initial state.
state = {
   dropdownsdata: []
};

//This is going into the api successcallback
if (responseText.success) {
  let all_dropdownData = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < responseText.data.length; i++) {
    let ind_dropdownData = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < responseText.data[i].choiceItems.length; j++) {
      let Add_On_Name = responseText.data[i].choiceItems[j].name;
      let temp = {};
      temp.value = Add_On_Name;
      ind_dropdownData.push(temp);
    }
    let temp_obj = {};
    temp_obj.label = responseText.data[i].name;
    temp_obj.data = ind_dropdownData;
    all_dropdownData.push(temp_obj);
  }
  this.setState({ dropdownsdata: all_dropdownData });
}
//Function for rendering n number of dropdowns.
renderDropdowns = () => {
  return this.state.dropdownsdata.map(e => {
    return <Dropdown label={e.label} data={e.data} />;
  });
};

render(){
  return <View>{this.renderDropdowns()}</View>;
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer !!!! It's correct and also i want to add label from my array into dropdown label. How can I do that also ?

Comment: I want to add ' responseText.data[i].name ' to my dropdown labels accordingly

Comment: @AkilaDevinda Hope the above latest edit helps you.

Comment: You can get it from either of the below methods that are available on Dropdown.                                                     
   || selectedIndex()    -->     Get selected index  --> Number ||
   || selectedItem()    -->     Get selected item .  --> Object ||